# Как вывести приоритетное значение, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть этот код:

```
if bussum < metrosum and taxisum:
    print("Bus")
if metrosum < bussum and taxisum:
    print("Metro")
if taxisum < metrosum and bussum:
    print("Taxi")
elif bussum == metrosum or taxisum:
    print("Bus")
elif metrosum == taxisum:
    print("Metro")
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в случае если выполнено два условия и переменная bus равна и меньше других переменных, выводилось только одно сообщение, у меня выводит сразу два "Bus"

Comment: Вы уверены, что условие `bussum < metrosum and taxisum` работает именно так как вы от него ожидаете? // намек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял суть вопроса, ты бы хотел, чтобы значение каждой переменной сравнивалось с двумя другими, но ты не совсем правильно используешь логические операции. Ответ, который ты хочешь получить выводится со следующими правками:

```
if bussum < metrosum and bussum < taxisum:
    print("Bus")
if metrosum < bussum and metrosum < taxisum:
    print("Metro")
if taxisum < metrosum and taxisum < bussum:
    print("Taxi")
elif bussum == metrosum or bussum == taxisum:
    print("Bus")
elif metrosum == taxisum:
    print("Metro")
```

Кроме того, надеюсь, ты понимаешь, что последние два оператора "elif" относятся к пятой строчке.
Советую тебя глянуть парочку видеороликов о логических операторах и условных операторах.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду больше смотреть материала про логические операторы)